# Custom WordPress theme: Shop page not found

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-theme

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme including WooCommerce. To modify the WooCommerce default templates, I simply added a `woocommerce.php` file to my themes root folder. Everything works fine except the shop page. Whichever page i assigned to shop page gets 404 page not found. All other things like single product, checkout, cart working smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried to flush the permalinks?

Comment: Yes! I have done that.. Even i deleted the shop page and recreated the blank page and reassigned.

Comment: Is there an error in your debug.log? (And please accept my edit of your question).

Comment: Nops! there is no error. There were warnings and i have corrected that. Don't know what is going wrong. Whichever page i assigned to shop page gets 404 page not found. All other things like single product, checkout, cart working smoothly.

Comment: Thats wired. Can you update your question and add the code you implemented in your theme?

Comment: @Mr.Jo I just added three  lines of code in woocommerce.php. 
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>

<?php  get_footer(); ?>